# CO2 Bottle inside or outside Keezer?

Tags: kegging, kegerator

I'm building a keezer and am not sure what to do with the CO2 bottle. Most folks seem to put it inside the freezer but this troubles my over beer'ed mind. Wouldn't the regulator give a different reading at lower temperatures?

Seems easy enough to punch a couple of holes through the back of the lid and have the bottle outside.

Comment: What is a keezer?

Comment: That's a whole other question. Try googling it first.

Comment: I agree this should probably be a separate question. However, it seems strange to me that you are directing me *away* from a homebrew forum to google in order to find the answer to a question related to homebrewing ...

Comment: Keezer = kegerator + freezer.  A chest freezer converted to a kegerator, usually by adding a wooden collar in which to install faucets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The co2 high pressure gage does show a lower reading at lower temperatures but the actual amount of CO2 in the tank is not decreased.  When the tank is full the gas is actually in liquid form and the gage will remain at the same reading until all of the liquid turns to gas.  At this point the gage will drop into the red area that usually says "order gas."  Thus the gage really only tells you if there is still CO2 in liquid form until it's almost gone.

Comment: But is the PSI readout correct, regardless of temperature?

Comment: The low pressure gauge that reads what pressure the beer is under is not affected by the temperature of the co2 tank.

Comment: Also, steel tanks will rust if the tank is kept inside.  This is usually not a problem, as most folks exchange tanks, but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks, still not sure where to put it. Am using a draft tower so might have it outside so it's easier to check.